# Using a Qt vista style Widget makes my USB/BLE data acquisition constantly faster....why?

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using a Nordic dev board (PCA10040, nRF52832) with modified "Nordic_HRM" firmware sending packets of 20bytes at 100Hz over Bluetooth Low Energy.

I'm using Nordic's heart_rate_collector example to retrieve the data on a Windows 10 computer using Nordic's USB BLE dongle (PCA10031). I tested both versions 2.2.1 and 4.0.0 of the pc-ble-driver. I modified the example code to report the data frequency of the last second (it originally reports the average data frequency for the whole session)

What I experience is very wierd:

- The heart_rate_collector example (win32 console app) retrieves data only at 65Hz. So looks like 35% of the data are being lost. I originally believed 100Hz sampling rate was too high for a BLE connection...
  [image]
- But, funny thing is that if I add a very simple GUI (`QApplication` and `QDialog`) to the project, then teh program is eventually able to receive data at 100Hz....but it depends on the mouse activity! When the mouse is over a button, frequency jumps to 100Hz, when it's not, it drops to 65Hz. I know it's hard to believe, so I did a video ;-)
  [image]
- And, even more funny, if I remove the Qt style plugin `qwindowsvistastyle.dll` from my installation folder, then GUI is hugly and then there is no way you can get the 100Hz anymore, you're stuck to 65Hz. I know it's also hard to believe, so I did another video ;-)
  [image]

When you are using vista display style, when the mouse is over a button, you see Qt does some repaint to draw the button focus. And I'm wondering if this probably reports to Windows that the process needs more attention and finally makes the OS give more attention to this process and then it looses less data?

Note that I tried to change the process priority to "High" in the task manager but this apparently has no effect.

Question is/are:

- Can anyone explain what's going on here?
- I'm not necessarily concerned about having the win32 console app be able to retrieve the data at 100Hz. But I'm really concerned about having my Qt app be able to do that, without requiring the user to be constantly moving his mouse around a button....is there anything that could be done (at QApplication level, Windows level, Nordic driver level....)?

---

The MCVE code:

mydialog.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QShowEvent>
#include <QLabel>

class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyDialog();
    ~MyDialog();

    void showEvent( QShowEvent* event ) override;

public slots:
    void toggle();
    void notify( uint32_t count, float freq );

private:
    int run();
    uint8_t cccd_value;
    uint32_t close();

    QLabel* label;
};
```

[main.cpp (modification of Nordic's main.c), fully available in pastbin](https://pastebin.com/mNzjg5LZ)

```
...

static MyDialog* notify_dialog = NULL;
static void on_hvx(const ble_gattc_evt_t * const p_ble_gattc_evt)
{
    clock_t now = clock();

    if (!m_hvx_start) {
        m_hvx_start = now;
    }

    m_hvx_count++;

    float seconds = (float)(now - m_hvx_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    if ( seconds >= 1 )
    {
        float pkt_per_sec = m_hvx_count / seconds;

        if ( notify_dialog )
            notify_dialog->notify( m_hvx_count, pkt_per_sec );

        printf("pkts: %06d, pkt/s: %f\n", m_hvx_count, pkt_per_sec);

        fflush(stdout);

        // reset counters
        m_hvx_start = clock();
        m_hvx_count = 0;
    }
}

...

MyDialog::MyDialog() 
{
    setLayout( new QVBoxLayout() );
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton( "Toggle", this );
    connect( button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(toggle()) );

    layout()->addWidget( button );
    layout()->addWidget( label = new QLabel( this ) );

    notify_dialog = this;
}

MyDialog::~MyDialog()
{
    notify_dialog = NULL;
    close();
}

void MyDialog::showEvent( QShowEvent* event )
{
    QDialog::showEvent( event );
    run();
}

int MyDialog::run()
{
    uint32_t error_code;
    char* serial_port;
    physical_layer_t * phy;
    data_link_layer_t * data_link_layer;
    transport_layer_t * transport_layer;

        cccd_value = 0;

    serial_port = UART_PORT_NAME;

    printf("Serial port used: %s\n", serial_port); fflush(stdout);

    phy = sd_rpc_physical_layer_create_uart(serial_port, 1000000, SD_RPC_FLOW_CONTROL_NONE, SD_RPC_PARITY_NONE);

    data_link_layer = sd_rpc_data_link_layer_create_bt_three_wire(phy, 100);

    transport_layer = sd_rpc_transport_layer_create(data_link_layer, 100);

    m_adapter = sd_rpc_adapter_create(transport_layer);

    //sd_rpc_log_handler_severity_filter_set(adapter, SD_RPC_LOG_INFO);

    error_code = sd_rpc_open(m_adapter, status_handler, ble_evt_dispatch, log_handler);

    if (error_code != NRF_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to open the nRF5 BLE Driver. Error code: 0x%02X\n", error_code);
        fflush(stdout);
        return error_code;
    }

    error_code = ble_stack_init();

    if (error_code != NRF_SUCCESS)
    {
        return error_code;
    }

    error_code = ble_options_set();

    if (error_code != NRF_SUCCESS)
    {
        return error_code;
    }

    scan_start();
}

void MyDialog::toggle()
{
    cccd_value ^= CCCD_NOTIFY;
    hrm_cccd_set(cccd_value);
}

uint32_t MyDialog::close()
{
    uint32_t error_code = sd_rpc_close(m_adapter);

    if (error_code != NRF_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to close the nRF5 BLE Driver. Error code: 0x%02X\n", error_code);
        fflush(stdout);
        return error_code;
    }

    printf("Closed\n"); fflush(stdout);

    return error_code;
}

void MyDialog::notify( uint32_t count, float freq )
{
    std::stringstream str;
    str << "During the last second, received " << count << " packets, frequency is " << freq << "Hz";
    label->setText( str.str().c_str() );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    MyDialog frame;
    frame.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

---

Edits

1. I realize the issue is not 100% percent reproductible. Sometimes, the console software is also able to retrieve data at 100Hz on my computer, sometimes not. I feel like after the PC was ON for some time and I did a lot of testing, it starts working at 100Hz for good. When I turn the computer OFF and back ON, it's always back to 65Hz data rate....
2. I added more data rate monitoring in the pc-ble-driver code itself and recompiled it. One in reder thread (`SerializationTransport::readHandler`), one in the code getting data from the USB connection (`UartBoost::readHandler`) for which I monitor the number of packets and the number of bytes received. Here is what I observe:

When data is received at 100Hz, I see:

```
UartBoost::readHandler: 000213, pkt/s: 212.362900
UartBoost::readHandler: 004315, bytes/s: 4302.093750
SerializationTransport::readHandler: 000103, pkt/s: 102.385681
pkts: 000102, pkt/s: 102.000000
```

When data is received at 65Hz, I see:

```
UartBoost::readHandler: 000061, pkt/s: 60.157787
UartBoost::readHandler: 002570, bytes/s: 2534.516602
SerializationTransport::readHandler: 000061, pkt/s: 60.157787
pkts: 000061, pkt/s: 60.157787
```

It's surprising that `UartBoost::readHandler` data rate (bytes/s) is reduced from 4302 to 2534 (same ratio reduced by ~40%, like final sampling rate), while the number of packets by second (pkt/s) is much more reduced by 71% (from 212 to 60). The BLE dongle sends 35% of data less but using 71% of packets less...I d'ont know what to conclude.

3. Added this piece of code in UartBoost::readHandler:

Added this:

```
std::cout << std::hex; 
for ( size_t pos = 0; pos != bytesTransferred; ++pos ) 
    std::cout << (unsigned) readBufferData[pos] << " "; 
std::cout << std::endl;
```

- Then, when reported data rate is 65Hz, I see in the console: https://pastebin.com/8wueXipJ
- And when it's 100Hz, I see: https://pastebin.com/iU6EQLcN

As you can see, the packets are splitted. At 65Hz, every packet is a full notification. At 100Hz, packets are splitted, meaning that many reads are necessary to get the full notification. This explains why at 65Hz we receive a few less bytes but a lot of less packets.

If I use notpad to clean the 100Hz packets to group them c0...c0, I get:
https://pastebin.com/FyFwR0yJ

very similar to the situation where we have 65Hz, but with ~35 more lines. This is expected.

So looks like Windows or the driver at some points prefers to send less data but in a cleaner way (not splitting the packets)....again, I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you tried using the driver in a thread other than the main thread? Put all BT-Code into a singleton and move that to a new QThread, see what happens. Anyway, this is not a BLE issue since the complete BT/BLE stack is on the USB device, it seems more likely to be a driver/USB issue.

Comment: @markus-nm: Actually, the dirver already creates a thread. The on_hvx is being called from a worker thread created by the driver itself. I don't see what more you think should be moved to a thread. The `run()` function (establishing the connection), the `toggle()` function (enabling BT notification)?

Comment: My point is that you are processing your BLE events in your main thread loop, which does all kinds of stuff, including handling GUI events. Have you tried to disable the notify() call in your on_hvx() function? 65Hz is very likely related to your monitor vertical refresh rate. If you've created a second thread and moved all BLE handling there, then no GUI events would disrupt/delay your packet handling. You could test it by simply removing the notify() call as I said already.

Comment: On another note: it's probably not a good idea to do any non-GUI performance metering on functions which directly interact with any user-interface, including the console. If your shell/terminal throttles output to 1 flush per vertical screen refresh, your bottleneck will be the fflush() call. Likewise updating your label-text probably doesn't happen more than once per vertical refresh, and your notify() call is waiting at that point. It might be better to use postEvent() et al, considering notify() might become deprecated in Qt6 (as per documentation).

Comment: @markus-nm: As I said, the driver creates a thread and `on_hxv` is being called from this thread. So the whole monitoring I do is from a thread anyway. Also, I doubt `notify` wil lever become depreciated as it's a function I declared myself. It's a good constation that observed frequency is the same as screen rate, but that can't be the issue at all as I print the message reporting observed sampling rate every second...as there is one fflush per second, I really don't understand how screen refresh rate could have any impact on this.